# Android: Deciding between SurfaceView and OpenGL (GLSurfaceView)

Tags: android, opengl-es

Is there a way to decide up front based on the expected complexity of a game/app in the planning phase whether to use regular Canvas drawing in a SurfaceView or to go with OpenGL?

I've been playing around with a Canvas and only need 2D movement, and on a fairly new phone I'm getting pretty decent performance with a bunch of primitive objects and a few bitmaps running around the screen on a solid background.

Is it fair to say that if I'm going to be drawing background images and increasing the number of objects being moved and drawn on top of them that I should go straight to OpenGL?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

All I can say is that it depends on how many sprites you're gonna use. Chris Pruett from Google has also documented this part very well.

[Google I/O 2009](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4Bk5rmIpic) and [Google I/O 2010](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-62tRHLcHk).

Below is a picture from one of his slides that are related to your topic:
[image]

With that knowledge, you should go with OpenGL using the `draw_texture` extension. Remember to query out the string and check if `draw_texture` is supported on the actual device.

For further information that are related to game development in general, see [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/game-development-for-android-quick.html).

Comment: But this picture doesn't show the load on ARM core vs GPU. When you render with OpenGL, you are moving the load to GPU while ARM core is available for other computing tasks. I believe Canvas ends up calling into Skia which mostly uses ARM cycles for rendering. Based on version of Android you are using, some parts of Skia seemed to be hardware accelerated.

Answer (score 11):

**SurfaceView**

> A GLSurfaceView is a SurfaceView that you can render into with OpenGL.
>   Choosing between them is simple:
>
> If you're familiar with OpenGL and need what it provides, use a
>   GLSurfaceView. Otherwise, use a SurfaceView. OpenGL is low-level. If
>   you're not already familiar with it, it's an undertaking to learn. If
>   you only need 2D drawing, SurfaceView uses the high-level, reasonably
>   high-performance Canvas. It's very easy to work with.
>
> Unless you have a strong reason to use a GLSurfaceView, you should use
>   a regular SurfaceView. I would suggest that if you don't already know
>   that you need GL, then you probably don't.

**OpenGL**

> OpenGL would be able to handle the rotations and scaling easily.
>
> Honestly, you would probably need to learn a lot of OpenGL to do this,
>   specifically related to the topics of:
>
> Geometry Lighting (or just disabling it) Picking (selecting geometry
>   to draw on it) Pixel Maps Texture Mapping Mipmapping Also, learning
>   OpenGL for this might be overkill, and you would have to be pretty
>   good at it to make it efficient.
>
> Instead, I would recommend using the graphic components of a game
>   library built on top of openGL, such as:
>
> [Cocos2d](http://cocos2d.org/)
>
> [libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/)
>
> [Any of the engines listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227759/android-game-engine-for-2d-and-3d-games)

**Source**

[Difference between SurfaceView and GLSurfaceView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029829/difference-between-surfaceview-and-glsurfaceview-in-android)

[Android: Canvas vs OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308521/android-canvas-vs-opengl)