# Android Camera Live Filter

Tags: android, surfaceview, glsurfaceview

What is the best way for Camera Live filters. I am recently using GPUImage Library from Link: https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimagelibrary.
Than I have found SurfaceView and GLSurfaceView.

Problem is:
How to apply live filter to camera using SurfaceView or GLSurfaceView.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This link uses Texture View

https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/LiveCameraActivity.java

This uses surface view to play a movie..u can manipulate it for live camera

https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/PlayMovieSurfaceActivity.java

To choose on whether to use surfaceView or GLSurfaceView

take a look at this 
[Difference between SurfaceView and GLSurfaceView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029829/difference-between-surfaceview-and-glsurfaceview-in-android)